# Export to Excel or CSV in Angular 6

Tags: node.js, mongodb, angular6, export-to-excel, export-to-csv

I have following table in angular 6 that is dynamically fetched from Database.

```
<table *ngIf="attendanceModel.length > 0; else attendanceModel_else" class="table table-responsive" id="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Designation</th>
        <th>Morning Session</th>
        <th>Evening Session</th>
        <th>Total Hours</th>
        <th>Status</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <ng-container *ngFor="let attendance of attendanceModel | groupBy:'employee_id'">
        <tr>
          <td colspan="6" class="text-center text-muted"> &laquo; Name: {{ attendance.key }} &raquo; </td>
        </tr>
        <tr *ngFor="let attendance of attendance.value">
            <td>{{attendance.employee_id.profile.first_name}} {{attendance.employee_id.profile.last_name}}</td>
            <td>{{attendance.employee_id.designation}}</td>
            <td>{{attendance.morning_session}}</td>
            <td>{{attendance.evening_session}}</td>
            <td>{{attendance.total_hours | number:'1.0-1' }}</td>
            <td *ngIf="attendance.status == 'Verified'; else inactive_else">
              <a class="btn btn-link text-success p-0" (click)="notVerify(attendance._id)">{{attendance.status}}</a>
            </td>
            <ng-template #inactive_else>
              <td *ngIf="attendance.status == 'Not Verified'">
                <a class="btn btn-link text-danger p-0" (click)="verify(attendance._id)">{{attendance.status}}</a>
              </td>
            </ng-template>
          </tr>
      </ng-container>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

I want to export the data in a customised format where the fields will be employee_name followed by any number of dates depending upon the database. Like

```
Name            Date1       Date2        Date3      ...so on
Employee 1      1/2/2018    2/2/2018    2/3/2018    ...
Employee 2      1/2/2018    2/2/2018    2/3/2018    ...
```

I have tried number of methods and npm but unable to understand how to achieve the above format.

Answer (score 8):

I was able to download a .xlsx file by following along with [this example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-export-xlsx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).

Comment: Thanks, how about styling the fonts, do we have any useful reference?

Comment: Use below commands to get the imports
`npm install file-saver — save`
`npm install xlsx — save`